# Static url does not redirect to the requested page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a question regarding the .htaccess file.
I have rewritten a dynamic url in a static one as following:
`www.mysite.com/index.php?lang=IT`
in
`www.mysite.com/it`

using this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^it/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

So far so good...

Now I need to create another static url for a dynamic url which redirects to the product description
www.mysite.com/product_details.php?id=1485

The rule inserted in the .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^it/prodotto-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.html$ /it/product_details.php?id=$1&lang=$2 [L]
```

Unfortunately if I click on the related link I cannot reach the requested page; but if I comment the first rule like this

```
#RewriteRule ^it/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

then I can see the page.
Do you know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Hi, I changed the regex, but I get the same result.

Comment: Put the second rule (prodotto...) first, otherwise the first one will match it and stop processing, as denoted by `[L]`

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that lang equals to language you want the script do like so?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^it/([^/]*).html$ /index.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^it/prodotto-([^/]*)-([^/]*).html$ /it/product_details.php?id=$1&lang=$2 [L]
```

this will do

```
yoursite.com/it/$1.html
```

and

```
yoursite.com/it/prodotto-$1-$2.html
```

?

Comment: Hi iJumbo,
Yes, I am trying to obtain the result above, but as said the second link does not work.

Comment: Like arco444 said the first rule will override the second one try to invert them or separate with a / the new url